# Timeout stops stream rxjs Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5, rxjs6, rxjs-pipeable-operators

Hi i want to keep getting data even after the timeout its reached i try some other way but no success (timeWith, repeatWhen ect)

here my code. now, any help would be good

goal: Device stops sending data = `timeout` alert user, device starts to get data again resume stream

```
  private gpsDevice(): Observable<Position> {
    return this.bluetooth.getBluetoothData().pipe(
      timeout(4000),
      switchMap((position) => {
       ...
        return of(position);
      }),
      catchError((error) => {
        console.error('Timeout occurred:', error);

        return EMPTY;
      }),
    );
  }
```

Comment: So you want to trigger an alert when the time is reached rather than throw an error?

Comment: i can throw an error nu the stream will be stopped i want to alert the user or send a error but not stop the stream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the docs for that operator [here](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/timeout).

You can use the `with` field to provide a callback when the timeout fires. That callback does not necessarily need to throw an error. Instead it could fire off a side effect that triggers a toast message, for example.

mySlowObservable$.pipe(
timeout({
each: 5000,
with: () => { trigger a toast message here },
})
)